# How to bind JavaScript array to dynamic HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add values of all the textboxes in the table created below using javascript, also the action column should contain two buttons as edit and delete for updation and deletion of the values of textboxes.[image]

I have created an array to hold the values of textboxes. 
Now on the click of save button I want to add these values to dynamic HTML table using Javascript(not angularJS or jQuery).
{

```
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

}

Comment: And what will happen on page refresh? Off-course, all inserted data will be vanished. :)

Comment: You can create a blank `table with necessary columns` either in html or on load. Then, you can append `tr` with mapped columns. You will have to create html string like: `"<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>...</td></tr>"`

Comment: that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function save() {
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + [id,name,gender,adress,email,"save"].join('</td><td>') + '</td>';
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```js
function updateTable() {
  
  var values = {
    id: document.getElementById("id").value,
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    gender: document.getElementById("gender").value,
    address: document.getElementById("address").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value
  };

  var table = document.getElementById("table");

  Object.keys(values).forEach(function (key) {
    table.getElementsByClassName(key + "Row")[0]
      .getElementsByClassName("value")[0]
      .textContent = values[key];
  });
}

document.getElementById("updateTable").addEventListener("click", updateTable);
```

```css
/* Purely cosmetic */
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
h1 { margin: 1em 0 0 0; font-size: 2em; }
#inputs { display: table; }
#inputs > span { display: table-row; }
#inputs label, #inputs input { display: table-cell; }
td { border: 1px solid #aaa; }
```

```html
<h1>Inputs</h1>
<form id="inputs">
  <span>
 <label for="id">ID</label> <input id="id">
  </span><span>
 <label for="name">Name</label> <input id="name">
  </span><span>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label> <input id="gender">
  </span><span>
    <label for="address">Address</label> <input id="address">
  </span><span>
 <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email">
  </span>
</form>

<h1>Table</h1>
<table id="table">
  <tr class="idRow"><td class="label">ID</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
  <tr class="nameRow"><td class="label">Name</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
  <tr class="genderRow"><td class="label">Gender</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
  <tr class="addressRow"><td class="label">Address</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
  <tr class="emailRow"><td class="label">Email</td><td class="value"></td></tr>
</table>

<button id="updateTable">Update table</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here my woking [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/xj9t0vj9/)

```
var mytable = [];
function Tbl() {
        var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var obj = {
        "id": id,
      "name": name,
      "gender": gender,
      "address": address,
      "email": email
    };
    mytable.push(obj);
    //create table
    var html = "<table>";
    mytable.forEach(function(entry) {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (var k in entry){
                html += "<td>" + entry[k] + "</td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    });
    html += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: There is an error as "can not set property innerHTML of null " in the last line of code.

Comment: look at my fiddle, there must be this <div id="result"></div> in your html